# Bypass NPM cache, if the module that I'm looking for is not there

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-ci

While working with NPM and its cache, I noticed that -sometimes- when the newest version of a certain package is not in the cache, `npm ci` errors out without bypassing NPM cache.

Is there a way to tell NPM something like "If the package you're looking for is not in the cache, then bypass the cache and try again"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a cache miss, `npm` will go to the registry. What are you seeing that makes you say it is behaving otherwise?

Comment: @trott today I faced a super weird issue with NPM not being able to see "@babel/traverse@7.15.3", it failed consistently until the IT guys deleted the NPM cache. After that it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

On a cache miss, `npm` will go to the registry. Cache corruption can cause weirdness, although recent versions of `npm` handle cache corruption fairly robustly. When in doubt, as you mention in your comment, deleting the cache can fix things, although the `npm` docs suggest avoiding it if at all possible. Use `npm cache clean` (or `npm cache clear` or `npm cache rm`) to clear the cache.